# integral of a series which is a function

Tags: matlab, series, integral

I am quite lost with this matlab code.I will appreciate any help.
I need to integrate a series, which is a function of a variable `x`, on the support of `x`.

I run the following:

```
m=10; % finite summation uptill m    

%Step1: I create a series function: \sum_{1}_{m}(x^{n})    
series=@(x,n)(sum(x.^(1:n)));    

%Styep2: I call the function for m=10, however x is still undefined    
ser=@(x)series(x,m);    

% Step3: I integrate over x in a given space for x    
h=integral(ser,1,2);
```

I get:

```
Error using  .^ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(x,n)(sum(x.^(1:n)))

Error in @(x)series(x,m)

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 89)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in test (line 9)
h=integral(ser,1,2);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integral` requires the function to be integrated to be able to handle vector arguments, so `ser` has to be able to evaluate `ser([1 2 3])` for example.

To allow `ser` to deal with vector inputs, use `arrayfun` to apply `series` to each element of the input `x` individually:

```
ser=@(x) arrayfun(@(z)series(z,m),x);
```